# Access web service running on VPN server

Tags: routes, vpn, iptables, pptp

I have an ubuntu 12.04 server running pptpd and my own web service that listens locally on port 5000.  If I make a vpn connection, how can I access the web service?

The idea being that I only want people with a vpn connection to be able to access the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have to do any additional settings.  Just had to go to the ip for eth0 with the desired port while connected to the vpn.